Getting the current date as input from the user and calculating the date for the 3,6,12,24 months ago
I want the program to ask the user for the current date. I was thinking something like:
date <- strsplit(readline("Please provide the Date (just hit ENTER to keep space: ")," ")

Then, I want to take that output and calculate the date 30 days prior, 3 months prior, 6 months prior, 12 months prior, 24 months prior.
I'm aware of
seq(as.Date("2012/12/31"), length=2, by="-6 months")[2]

But I need the output from what the user has entered.

The date that is entered should be saved in the date object. You can just ask somebody to enter it in yyyy/mm/dd format (get rid of the strsplit) with readline and then as.Date(date) in the next step.

If you are looking for strictly the current date (rather than the user being able to supply a date other than today) you could play around with having it auto-populate using format(Sys.time(), '%m/%d/%Y')

Please define your understanding of the unit named “month”.

Wow thank you so much! Works great. How do I do it so all the user has to do is enter the date and then an output file is created showing 3 months prior date, 6 mths prior date and so on.

Using sprintf.
> lapply(c(1/2, 3, 6, 12, 24), \(m) 
+        seq.Date(as.Date("2012/12/31"), length=2, 
+                 by=sprintf("-%s months", m))[2])
[[1]]
[1] "2012-12-31"

[[2]]
[1] "2012-10-01"

[[3]]
[1] "2012-07-01"

[[4]]
[1] "2011-12-31"

[[5]]
[1] "2010-12-31"

You may wrap it in a function that uses readline().
> fn <- \(periods=c(1/2, 3, 6, 12, 24)) {
+   repeat {
+     input <- readline('Input date YYYY-MM-DD: ')
+     d <- tryCatch(as.Date(input), error=\(e) NA)
+     if (is.na(d) || !is.na(suppressWarnings(as.integer(input)))) {
+       message(sprintf('%s not a valid date, need format YYYY-MM-DD',
+                       sQuote(input)))
+     } else {
+       break
+     }
+   }
+   lapply(c(1/2, 3, 6, 12, 24), \(m) 
+          seq.Date(d, length=2, 
+                   by=sprintf("-%s months", m))[2])
+ }


> fn()
Input date YYYY-MM-DD: 2024-04-05
[[1]]
[1] "2024-04-05"

[[2]]
[1] "2024-01-05"

[[3]]
[1] "2023-10-05"

[[4]]
[1] "2023-04-05"

[[5]]
[1] "2022-04-05"


> fn()
Input date YYYY-MM-DD: 12345
‘12345’ not a valid date, need format YYYY-MM-DD
Input date YYYY-MM-DD:

